# Cannot invoke HTTP POST method from C# - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post, internal-server-error

I have created a web api project and implemented the below HTTP POST method.

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("updateProfile")]
    public IHttpActionResult updateProfile([FromBody]RequestDataModel request)
    {
        // MY CODE

    }

    public class RequestDataModel
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my WebAPIConfig class.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And I tried to invoke this method from my C# application.

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var account = new { FullName = "Test", Age = 25 };

        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        // HTTP POST
        var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:63648/api/Account/updateProfile", content);
        if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           // MY CODE
        }
    }
```

But it returns an error as "Internal Server Error".

[image]

Comment: "Internal Server Error" usually means the target API throwing unhandled exception. Check if `updateProfile` contains any error using debugger.

Comment: I have put a break point. But the method does not get hit

Comment: Can you share your WebApiConfig class? Can be found under "App_Start" folder.

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita I have updated the question with WebApiConfig class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in routeTemplate of WebApiConfig class.

The routeTemplate should be `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` instead of `api/{controller}/{id}`

See below.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```